DHCP takes forever - Imaginary ACD conflict
For the past year, I've had increasing difficulty to connect to my work's network. Wifi is disabled, I get an IPv6 immediately, but it takes between 1 and 30min to obtain an IPv4 address. Unplug/replug of the cable does not seem to help.
My log shows many instances of this before finally accepting:
NetworkManager[2009]: <info>  [1719213903.5664] dhcp4 (eth0): state changed new lease, address=134.158.40.175, acd conflict
NetworkManager[2009]: <info>  [1719213951.4824] dhcp4 (eth0): canceled DHCP transaction

And no, there is no duplicate IP on the network. Similarly the server shows:
dhcpd[3361397]: DHCPDISCOVER from 38:14:28:ab:e8:29 via ens192
dhcpd[3361397]: DHCPOFFER on 134.158.40.175 to 38:14:28:ab:e8:29 via ens192
dhcpd[3361397]: DHCPREQUEST for 134.158.40.175 (134.158.40.18) from 38:14:28:ab:e8:29 via ens192
dhcpd[3361397]: DHCPACK on 134.158.40.175 to 38:14:28:ab:e8:29 via ens192
dhcpd[3361397]: DHCPDECLINE of 134.158.40.175 from 38:14:28:ab:e8:29 via ens192: not found

Anything I can do to diagnose or fix this ?
EDIT:
There is also this message:
IP address 134.158.40.175 cannot be configured because it is already in use in the network by host 04:56:E5:5D:06:F1

But this MAC corresponds to my wifi. The DHCP normally gives the same IP both on wifi and ethernet, so I disable wifi when I arrive at work, but that's apparently not enough, the server seems to remember it. Is it a server problem or a client problem (not sending some kind of disconnect maybe) ?

Look at the network logs with the terminal command: sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager.  Also do: service NetworkManager status and service --status-all.

Thanks. I added some info: it stems from a conflict between wifi and ethernet, even if wifi is off.
